# Requisição da pagina em localhost demora 20 segundos pra abrir

Tags: php

Estou tentando mostrar dados do banco em uma tabela.

```
    <html lang="en">
<head>




   <title>Estoque</title>

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Bootstrap theme -->
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" </script>
<script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<div class="container">  
        <table>
            <tr><b>
                <td>Código Produto</td>
                <td>Descrição</td>
                <td>Preço</td>
                <td>Quantidade Estoque</td>
            </tr></b>


<?php
REQUIRE_ONCE "conexao.php";
$sql = "SELECT id, cod_produto, dsc_produto, preco_produto, qtd_estoque, qtd_limitador FROM estoque";
$result = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
        { 

?>


            <tr bgcolor="<?php echo $bg ?>">
                <td><?php echo $row[cod_produto] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row[dsc_produto] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row[preco_produto] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row[qtd_estoque] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row[qtd_limitador] ?></td>



                <td>
                    <form method="get" action="edit.php">
                        <button type="hidden" name="id" class="btn btn-default" value="<?php echo $row[id]?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button>
                    </form>
                    <form method="POST" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
                    <button type="button" name="botaoDelete" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" value="<?php echo $row[id] ?>" data-target="#myModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                    </form>
                </td>
                </tr>



    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Excluir produto</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Você tem certeza que deseja excluir?</p>

  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <form method="POST">
    <button type="button" name="botaoConfirma" value="<?php echo $dlt ?>" class="btn btn-danger">Excluir</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btnn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
    </form>


<?php      
    if (isset($_POST["botaoDelete"])) {
    $dlt = $_POST["botaoDelete"];
        if (isset($_POST["botaoConfirma"])) {
            $cnf = $_POST["botaoConfirma"];
            $deleteSql = mysqli_query($conexao, "DELETE * FROM estoque WHERE id='".$cnf."'");
        }

}

}   
?> 

  </div>
</div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->


</tbody>
</div>
</body>
```

Quando chamo no navegador, demora em torno de 20s pra abrir.
Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Quantos itens retorna essa sua consulta ao mysql?

Comment: revise as conexões com o banco de dados.

Comment: Só uma dica, seu <script src="bootstrap/js...> não está fechando a tag ">" fazendo com o que o proximo fique aberto...

Comment: Estabeleça sempre um limite de registro para mostrar, por exemplo, na primeira página de 1 a 10, na segunda de 10 a 20, por exemplo. Tenha cuidado para não selecionar as linhas inteiras, ainda mais se tratando de uma aplicação web.

Comment: As conexões com o banco estão ok e essa consulta retorna em torno de 30 linhas. Na verdade, ele retorno 20 e metade da linha 21. Devo fazer uma paginação agora no início? Imagino que 30 linhas não seja tão grande a ponto de demorar tanto.

Comment: Reduzi as linhas para 5 e mesmo assim está demorando uns 20 segundos pra carregar.

Answer (score 1):

Você está usando o Windows? Se estiver, verifique se seu servidor está servindo conexões apenas via IPv4. Se estiver, é possível que este seja o seu problema.

O que está acontecendo é que o Windows por padrão direciona o endereço "localhost" para o loopback via IPv6 (endereço `::1`). Se o seu servidor estiver servindo apenas IPv4, a conexão não fecha e fica aguardando o timeout (que no seu caso devem ser esses 20s). Quando dá o timeout então ele tenta o endereço IPv4 (`127.0.0.1`), o que completa a conexão.

Se seu problema for este (e não algo mais no PHP), a solução é você configurar seu servidor para aceitar conexões no loopback via IPv6 ou configurar o seu cliente para conectar ao endereço `127.0.0.1` em vez de `localhost`.

Comment: Já configurei (havia visto em outro posto do SO) e mesmo assim persiste o erro, o que me leva à outra dúvida. Mesmo sendo iniciante, vale a pena instalar uma distribuição do Linux e começar aprender lá?